# I have broken my poetry installation, and I don't know where to begin to fix it

Tags: python, linux-mint, pyenv, python-poetry, pyenv-virtualenv

I was using poetry in combination with pyenv for some hobby projects. I created some virtualenvs with pyenv inside some poetry hobby projects. For some reason, I deleted some of these python installs that broke the virtualenvs within these projects and now poetry won't work anymore. I'm getting this message when I try to start poetry. I'm using Linux Mint 20.1:

```
/home/milkman/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py2.7/subprocess32.py:149: RuntimeWarning: The _posixsubprocess module is not being used. Child process reliability may suffer if your program uses threads.
  "program uses threads.", RuntimeWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/milkman/.poetry/bin/poetry", line 16, in <module>
    from poetry.console import main
  File "/home/milkman/.poetry/lib/poetry/console/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .application import Application
  File "/home/milkman/.poetry/lib/poetry/console/application.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .commands.about import AboutCommand
  File "/home/milkman/.poetry/lib/poetry/console/commands/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .check import CheckCommand
  File "/home/milkman/.poetry/lib/poetry/console/commands/check.py", line 2, in <module>
    from poetry.factory import Factory
  File "/home/milkman/.poetry/lib/poetry/factory.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .repositories.pypi_repository import PyPiRepository
  File "/home/milkman/.poetry/lib/poetry/repositories/pypi_repository.py", line 33, in <module>
    from ..inspection.info import PackageInfo
  File "/home/milkman/.poetry/lib/poetry/inspection/info.py", line 25, in <module>
    from poetry.utils.env import EnvCommandError
  File "/home/milkman/.poetry/lib/poetry/utils/env.py", line 23, in <module>
    import virtualenv
  File "/home/milkman/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py2.7/virtualenv/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .run import cli_run, session_via_cli
  File "/home/milkman/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py2.7/virtualenv/run/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .plugin.activators import ActivationSelector
  File "/home/milkman/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py2.7/virtualenv/run/plugin/activators.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .base import ComponentBuilder
  File "/home/milkman/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py2.7/virtualenv/run/plugin/base.py", line 5, in <module>
    from backports.entry_points_selectable import entry_points
ImportError: No module named entry_points_selectable
```

I have no idea where to start to fix this. Anytime I try a command with poetry I get this same message. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you have deleted some library files. You can try removing poetry and all libraries that your app is using. Start fresh installation of poetry.
You can use `pip` to install and uninstall.

Other wise start a new project from fresh.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you accidentally deleted some of the library's functions. Try just removing it and reinstalling.

Comment: Thank you!

EDIT: I wrote a comment on not being able to uninstall Poetry but apparently I didn't have the installer on my computer which is needed to uninstall Poetry.